# Doctrine2 + Zend2 Repository class not found

Tags: class, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity

module.config.php

```
 'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'Application_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entities')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                 'Application\Entities' =>  'Application_driver'
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Article.php

```
namespace Application\Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_article_gallery1", columns={"gallery_idgallery"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_article_sf_guard_user1", columns={"sf_guard_user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\ArticleRepository")
 */
```

ArticleRepository.php is in Application\Entities\Repositories\

And I get error `Fatal error: Class 'Repositories\ArticleRepository' not found`

I try multiple path but its not working.

I dont have a clue what I doing wrong

I also try

```
php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-repositories ./module/Application/src/Application/Entities
```

and its creates Entities/Repositories/ArticleRepository.php but still I get error

Comment: I found solution

in ArticleRepository.php was

    namespace Repositories;

must be

    namespace Application\Entities\Repositories;